# Get the string until a line break, and the rest of it on another variable in Java

Tags: java, string, split

I'm trying to get the first paragraph of a text (until a line break) on a variable, and the rest thing in another variable.

For example for a text like:

> hello how are you im really fine thank you, and you, im fine. thanks a
>   lot good bye. 
>   foo bar random text foo bar random text foo bar random
>   text foo bar random text foo bar random text .
> blahblahblah
>   blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah.

My aim is to get on

```
String firstpart = "hello how are you im really fine thank you, and you, im fine. thanks a lot good bye."
String restofit = "foo bar random text foo bar random text foo bar random text foo bar random text foo bar random text \n lahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah blahblahblah."
```

This is my try:

```
String[] result = mytext.split("\n", 2);
System.out.println(result[0]);
if (result[1] != null) System.out.println("nas");
```

But I'm getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1` on the `result[1]` line (maybe not with the text of the example, but with my real text), when the input string is only composed by one line.

Is my approach correct? How can I fix the error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just check the size of the output array before accessing the 1st index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash:

```
String[] result = mytext.split("\\R",2);
//check length of result:
if(result.length >1){
    //do what you need with result[1];
}
```

Java turns a double backslash `\\` in a string into one backslash in runtime. This is because of special characters such as `"`,`'`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same error on the same line.

Comment: There is no difference for a regex engine whether you pass a literal newline or a regex escape sequence.

Comment: Yes, no one thinks about line breaks... In Java 7, use `.split("\\R", 2)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I keep forgetting about that

Comment: @Avión you asked about a string with two lines... I'm very confused... what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Having an input string which can be 1 or more lines, I'm getting the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when the string has only 1 line. I missed that part on the question, yes, sorry.

Comment: oh, well that's because you are trying to access an index that doesn't exist... you should check the length of `result`